# Calculate roll angle for Google Maps Street View

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Preamble: there's an [issue logged](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6288) with the Google Maps API, requesting the ability to correct the roll angle of street view tiles to compensate for hills.  I've come up with a client-side workaround involving some css sorcery on the tile container.  Here's my rotate function:

```
rotate: function() {
    var tilesLoaded = setInterval(function() {
        var tiles = $('map-canvas').getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i=0; i<tiles.length; i++) {
            if (tiles[i].src.indexOf(maps.panorama.getPano()) > -1) {
                if (typeof maps.panorama.getPhotographerPov != 'undefined') {
                    var pov = maps.panorama.getPhotographerPov(),
                    pitch = pov.pitch,
                    cameraHeading = pov.heading;

                    /**************************
                    // I need help with my logic here.
                    **************************/
                    var yaw = pov.heading - 90;
                    if (yaw < 0) yaw += 360;
                    var scale = ((Math.abs(maps.heading - yaw) / 90) - 1) * -1;
                    pitch = pov.pitch * scale;


                    tiles[i].parentNode.parentNode.style.transform = 'rotate(' + pitch + 'deg)';
                    clearInterval(tilesLoaded);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }, 20);
}
```

A full (and more thoroughly commented) proof-of-concept is at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/calraith/L3abko68/).  Oddly, the horizon is just about perfectly level if I do no calculation at all on the example in the JSFiddle, but that result isn't consistent for every Lat/Lng.  That's just a coincidence.

So, I need to calculate the roll at the client's heading, given the client heading, photographer's heading, and photographer's pitch.  Assume the photographer is either facing uphill or downhill, and `pov.pitch` is superlative (at the min or max limit).  How can I calculate the desired pitch facing the side at a certain degree?

**Edit:** I found an equation that seems to work pretty well.  I updated the code and the fiddle.  While it seems to be pretty close to the answer, my algorithm is linear.  I believe the correct equation should be logarithmic, resulting in subtler adjustments closer to the camera heading and opposite, while to the camera's left and right adjustments are larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for.  The calculation involves spherical trigonometry, which I didn't even know existed before researching this issue.  If anyone notices any problems, please comment.   Or if you have a better solution than the one I found, feel free to add your answer and I'll probably accept it if it's more reliable or significantly more efficient than my own.

Anyway, if the tile canvas is a sphere, 0 pitch (horizon) is a plane, and camera pitch is another plane intersecting at the photographer, the two planes project a [spherical lune](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalLune.html) onto the canvas.  This lune can be used to calculate a [spherical triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTriangle.html) where:

1. polar angle = Math.abs(camera pitch)
2. base = camera heading - client heading
3. one angle = 90° (for flat horizon)

With two angles and a side available, other properties of a spherical triangle can be calculated using the [spherical law of sines](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTrigonometry.html).  The entire triangle isn't needed -- only the side opposite the polar angle.  Because this is math beyond my skills, I had to borrow the logic from [this spherical triangle calculator](https://files.nyu.edu/emf202/public/js/spherical.html).  Special thanks to emfril!

[The jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/calraith/L3abko68/) has been updated.  My production roll getter has been updated as follows:

```
function $(what) { return document.getElementById(what); }

var maps = {

    get roll() {
        function acos(what) {
            return (Math.abs(Math.abs(what) - 1) < 0.0000000001)
            ? Math.round(Math.acos(what)) : Math.acos(what);
        }
        function sin(what) { return Math.sin(what); }
        function cos(what) { return Math.cos(what); }
        function abs(what) { return Math.abs(what); }
        function deg2rad(what) { return what * Math.PI / 180; }
        function rad2deg(what) { return what * 180 / Math.PI; }
        var roll=0;

        if (typeof maps.panorama.getPhotographerPov() != 'undefined') {
            var pov = maps.panorama.getPhotographerPov(),
            clientHeading = maps.panorama.getPov().heading;
            while (clientHeading < 0) clientHeading += 360;
            while (clientHeading > 360) clientHeading -= 360;

            // Spherical trigonometry method
            a1 = deg2rad(abs(pov.pitch));
            a2 = deg2rad(90);
            yaw = deg2rad((pov.heading < 0 ? pov.heading + 360 : pov.heading) - clientHeading);
            b1 = acos((cos(a1) * cos(a2)) + (sin(a1) * sin(a2) * cos(yaw)));

            if (sin(a1) * sin(a2) * sin(b1) !== 0) {

                roll = acos((cos(a1) - (cos(a2) * cos(b1))) / (sin(a2) * sin(b1)));
                direction = pov.heading - clientHeading;
                if (direction < 0) direction += 360;
                if (pov.pitch < 0)
                    roll = (direction < 180) ? rad2deg(roll) * -1 : rad2deg(roll);
                else
                    roll = (direction > 180) ? rad2deg(roll) * -1 : rad2deg(roll);

            } else {

                // Fall back to algebraic estimate to avoid divide-by-zero
                var yaw = pov.heading - 90;
                if (yaw < 0) yaw += 360;
                var scale = ((abs(clientHeading - yaw) / 90) - 1) * -1;
                roll = pov.pitch * scale;
                if (abs(roll) > abs(pov.pitch)) {
                    var diff = (abs(roll) - abs(pov.pitch)) * 2;
                    roll = (roll < 0) ? roll + diff : roll - diff;
                }

            }
        }
        return roll;        
    }, // end maps.roll getter

    // ... rest of maps object...

} // end maps{}
```

After rotating the panorama tile container, the container also needs to be expanded to hide the blank corners.  I was originally using the 2D law of sines for this, but I found a [more efficient shortcut](http://polymathprogrammer.com/2012/02/22/optimal-width-height-after-image-rotation/).  Thanks Mr. Tan!

```
function deg2rad(what) { return what * Math.PI / 180; }
function cos(what) { return Math.cos(deg2rad(what)); }
function sin(what) { return Math.sin(deg2rad(what)); }

var W = $('map-canvas').clientWidth,
H = $('map-canvas').clientHeight,
Rot = Math.abs(maps.originPitch);

// pixels per side
maps.growX = Math.round(((W * cos(Rot) + H * cos(90 - Rot)) - W) / 2);
maps.growY = Math.round(((W * sin(Rot) + H * sin(90 - Rot)) - H) / 2);
```

There will be no more edits to this answer, as I don't wish to have it converted to a community wiki answer yet.  As updates occur to me, they will be applied to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/calraith/L3abko68/).

Comment: I should note that, although I continue to calculate `maps.growX` in the manner shown in the example above, I switched to calculating `maps.growY` as a proportion.  This way, the aspect ratio is not changed.  See the fiddle for the update.